# How to know whether a WebForms Control is rendered the first time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, controls, postback

I have a WebForms page with several instances of an [.ascx UserControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb3w5b53%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) on it. Those controls are on certain tabs of a tabbed view (asp:MultiView). Thus, only one of those controls is visible if at all.

Those controls show current data from a remote service. **I want to fetch the data from the remote service only once, at the first time each control is shown** (or the user clicks an explicit refresh button). The control just keeps the data using `EnableViewState = true`.

I currently have

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnPreRender(e);
    Refresh(); //call the web service
    }
}
```

but this calls the web service when shown, **every time.**

On pages, we have the `!Page.IsPostBack` trick, but this does of course not work for controls, especially not when displayed only later.

**But how to fetch the data "the first time shown" only?**

Note: I know I could store that on ViewState myself, but isn't there a way using existing methods/data?

Comment: Are you looking for [UserControl.IsPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.usercontrol.ispostback.aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately this seems to be only a copy of the page's `IsPostBack`, because it does not change after showing the control the first time (if it's not shown at initial page load)

Comment: if you think your problem can be seen as a caching issue, maybe this can be of some help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h30h475z%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: @jbl Very interesting. I didn't know about that. But what about the possibility to have explicit refreshes? It seems this would not be possible anymore?

Comment: following the links on @Outputcache ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdxfb6cy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx ), you will see some VaryByParams/VaryByControls attributes. I guess it can also be used to force refresh (like using dummy query string parameters to force refresh of ajax calls)

Answer (score -1):

try a boolean

```
bool isLoaded = false;

Page_Load()
{
   if(!isLoaded)
   {
      // Actual process here like data fill and etc. . . .
      isLoaded = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: While this will work, unfortunately I feel this is is somewhat like what I mentioned in my note.